# Spring Boot 2.3 with JPA: CommandLineRunner finish delayed

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a CommandLineRunner on Spring Boot 2.3.3 using JPA which has a 1 minute delay after finishing (see log below). This happens even when there are no entity classes present and there is no JPA operation. It's reproducible with a project consisting of only a mainly empty main class.

This did not occur with version 2.2.7, but does on 2.3.1. It happens not only on h2 but also on other databases (derby, oracle). If I use only spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc instead of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa there is no delay.

Is there any way to avoid this delay?

```
2020-09-01 10:51:57.408  INFO 30314 --- [           main] testcase.SlowShutdown                    : Starting SlowShutdown on io with PID 30314 
2020-09-01 10:51:57.410  INFO 30314 --- [           main] testcase.SlowShutdown                    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-01 10:51:57.858  INFO 30314 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-09-01 10:51:57.873  INFO 30314 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-01 10:51:58.095  INFO 30314 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-01 10:51:58.100  INFO 30314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-01 10:51:58.171  INFO 30314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-01 10:51:58.216  INFO 30314 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-01 10:51:58.243  INFO 30314 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-09-01 10:51:58.274  INFO 30314 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-09-01 10:51:58.274  INFO 30314 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-09-01 10:51:58.282  INFO 30314 --- [           main] testcase.SlowShutdown                    : Started SlowShutdown in 1.118 seconds (JVM running for 1.579)
2020-09-01 10:51:58.283  INFO 30314 --- [           main] testcase.SlowShutdown                    : start
2020-09-01 10:51:58.315  INFO 30314 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-01 10:51:58.387  INFO 30314 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-09-01 10:51:58.498  INFO 30314 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-01 10:51:58.502  INFO 30314 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-01 10:52:58.512  INFO 30314 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-01 10:52:58.513  INFO 30314 --- [extShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-09-01 10:52:58.519  INFO 30314 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-01 10:52:58.521  INFO 30314 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-09-01 10:52:58.529  INFO 30314 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>slowshutdown</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>slowshutdown</name>
  <description>slowshutdown</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Main class:

```
package testcase;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SlowShutdown implements CommandLineRunner {
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SlowShutdown.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SlowShutdown.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    log.info("start");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SlowShutdown implements CommandLineRunner {
}
```

Comment: This looks like a natural solution. While jccampaneros answer solves the shutdown problem, with this I can use deferred mode for faster startup time.

Comment: It is right, I only focused the response in provide you a solution to solve the shutdown problem, but with this configuration you can take profit of the deferred mode for faster startup time. If you think so, the change Spring Boot did is for provide the user a benefit, faster startup, and in our code the change was causing just the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot 2.3 version ships with a new major release of Spring Data.

As they indicate in the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#bootstrapmode-for-jpa-repositories), they changed the default `BootstrapMode` for JPA repositories:

> As of [#16230](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16230), the default `BootstrapMode` for JPA repositories is now "deferred" so as to improve startup time. You can revert that new default with the `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default` configuration property.

To avoid the delay, you only need to create an `application.properties` file, and define the property `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode`as indicated:

```
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
```

Comment: This really seems to solve the issue. I think it is strange that a switch that controls initialization blocks the shutdown.